# Failed to validate dict when adding it as a new field in pydantic-redis example

Tags: python-3.8, pydantic

I am learning pydantic-redis,and I tried to modify the example at
https://github.com/sopherapps/pydantic-redis

by adding a new field `new_field: dict = {}` as follows

```
class Book(Model):
    _primary_key_field: str = 'title'
    title: str
    author: str
    published_on: date
    in_stock: bool = True
    new_field: dict = {}
```

when I run the example it says (in the end):
`value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)`

I have also tried other types, like `new_field: List[int] = [8]` (and then importing typing.List)
On the other hand, when I add a new field with a primitive type like int, everything works fine.

What have I missed?

Best regards

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you're using `new_field: dict` ?

Comment: The error is triggered when the Books.select() call is made(in the "Getting started" example in the URL in my post):

`# Select all books to view them. A list of Model instances will be returned`

`all_books = Book.select()`

So I guess there is a validation going on there, that fails. Sorry, I didn't manage to insert newlines in this comment...

Answer (score 1):

I asked the author, and it turned out it was a bug. Now it's fixed, and my example works!
Just install the latest version, 0.1.2, and there is a modified example with some nested data. Works fine :-)

BR,
David